# Using design definition for computed properties

Tags: xpages

I cant find a solution for this problem. I am using design definitions for almost all my controls.

They are working fine the only problem i have is that if i am computing one of the properties i cant use the property anymore in the design definition. It will create a text in red and the xpages will prompt some error messages.

Is there a way to ask if the property is computed and show a standard text instead.

This is the design definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"     xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:inputText type="text" value="<%=this.field_name %>"></xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

Whenever the value of the property field_name is computed in the custom control it brings up that error.

Anybody any ideas?

When I insert the Field custom control with a static text value for field_name, the design definition will display the field_name properly.

```
<xc:Field field_type="text" field_name="myfield_1"></xc:Field>
```

If I insert the Field custom control with a computed text value for field_name, it doesn't:

```
<xc:Field field_type="text"><xc:this.field_name><![CDATA[#  {javascript:"myfield_"+@Text(1)}]]></xc:this.field_name>
</xc:Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure field_name is the exact name of the property passed in as CompositeData. For example, I was able to reference the string property 'create' to create the image of field this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputText value="<%=this.create%>">
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

So, I suspect it's a typo, a missing property, or not a string.

Comment: I am afraid you dont get me. If i just enter a string as a parameter it works but if i am computing something the parameter controls text becomes red.  An example  "myfield" works fine "myfield_"+@Text(index) makes the custom controls text red and error messages pop up in designer

Comment: Could you put the actual code you're trying in the post, then?

Comment: Added. The code works in the browser its just that the designer is giving me error messages

Comment: The design definition only displays in the designer anyway, so the client never looks at it.

Comment: Doesnt matter. I have to click almost 30 times when i open or save an xpage because i am using some cc in a repeat control. Thats why i wanted to get rid of it

Comment: Wait, what are you clicking 30 times when opening or saving? Is it giving you an ECL alert asking you to authorize the action? Having a design definition ONLY affects how the custom control is displayed when you look at the element in which the custom control is embedded when using Designer. It has no effect on the client experience.